# Is this a good strategy to optimise web images for iphone?

Tags: iphone, graphics

I have a lot of old assets (html and image files) I need to optimise for mobile devices. The existing assets were created for desktop and did not have mobile device in mind.

I am planning to make the following changes:

1) In front end, if it is running on a desktop device, its content will be loaded form the existing url (e.g. `static.example.com/document1/index.html`). But if the website is loaded from an  iphone6, it will switch to `static.example.com/document1_iphone6/index.html`

2) `document1_iphone6` is basically a duplicate of `document1`. All the image assets will be resized to fit 750x1334

Is there any problem/flaw with this plan?

Comment: This is probably better suited for SO, but why not use responsive images with `srcset`? That would also support (newer) Androids and wouldn't just limit your optimizations to iPhone. How would you be detecting the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track of optimizing images for mobile devices, but I think that the way you are going about it won't scale very well. If you just target iPhones with resized images, you're going to be supporting 5 different sizes, iPhone 6+, iPhone 6, iPhone 5/5S, iPhone 4/4S, plus the original, which isn't that bad.

But what if you want to support Android phones at the same level, having an image for every device made? You're going to end up with dozens of different image sizes.

[Android screen resoultions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587854/is-there-a-list-of-screen-resolutions-for-all-android-based-phones-and-tablets/23009368#23009368)

Here is another link with a larger list of device sizes.

[mydevice.io common smartphone sizes](http://mydevice.io/devices/)

Not only will you have dozens of different devices, but your naming scheme won't work that well, as some resolutions are used for multiple displays, leaving you with duplicates of images.

A better way to optimize for mobile is to target screen resolutions instead of devices. For example, you could target a set of resolutions like

> xxxhdpi: 1280x1920 px
>   xxhdpi: 960x1600 px
>   xhdpi: 640x960 px
>   hdpi: 480x800 px
>   mdpi: 320x480 px
>   ldpi: 240x320 px

With this method, you can support all mobile devices with just 6 different sizes, plus, when a new device is launched, you won't need to resize every image on your site for the new device.

This is all assuming you are just talking about resizing your image assets. If you are going to be redoing your layout for every device, you would be much, much better creating a responsive site that scales for mobile devices.